# Joomla 3.1 Category list date format

Tags: joomla3.1

currently the date displayed in the page that uses category list is like this 31/05/13 ..
how do i change it into Friday, 22 March 2013..
ive already tried changing the en-GB.ini file but to no avail..
btw..i use the blog layout

Comment: Which layout are you using? Blog or default?

Comment: i use the blog layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php` to `templates/<your_template>/html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php` and edit as you like (you can copy `modify_date.php` and `create_date.php` as well). In your case it's sufficient to replace `DATE_FORMAT_LC3` by `DATE_FORMAT_LC1`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a Language Override

For Joomla 3.x
Language Manager -> Overrides -> NEW
Language Constant: DATE_FORMAT_LC3
Text: F j, Y

This would produce as an example October 23, 2013

Date formats info can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For Joomla 2.5.x
Language Constant is DATE_FORMAT_LC2

Answer (score 0):

Use the language override in Joomla 3+ to avoid conflicts in the future. Go to Extensions/Language Manager, then click the "Overrides" menu on the left. Once inside, click the "New" button on the top left, then perform a search for the date format. For blogs, I'm guessing you'll need to search for "DATE_FORMAT_LC3" in the search filter (right side of screen), but you may need to experiment. Edit the settings on the left once you've selected the appropriate field to edit, then click save. You'll probably want to change it to something like "l, d F Y" (don't use quotes). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more possibilities.