# Joomla content blog layout

Tags: joomla

after 6 hours search and test any files in com_content,i still can't find any files can change the Blog's layout 'article-info muted' this correct Div ,there are only 'article-info muted' Div in com_content/archive/default_items.php

I want  change the icon and Date Format in this div,where i can find it?thanks!

Closed!

Comment: finially find the solution!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975419/joomla-3-1-category-list-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution Here

[Joomla 3.1 Category list date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975419/joomla-3-1-category-list-date-format)

> Copy layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php to
>   templates//html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/publish_date.php
>   and edit as you like (you can copy modify_date.php and create_date.php
>   as well). In your case it's sufficient to replace DATE_FORMAT_LC3 by
>   DATE_FORMAT_LC1.